# Как сравнить значение одного массива с ключами другого?

Tags: массивы, php, сравнение

Добрый день (вечер, ночь).

У меня есть два массива:

1. `$array['key']['value']`
2. `$array_sec['array']['array2']['keys']['value']`

И мне надо сравнить key первого массива со всеми именованиями `array2` (их может быть много).

В общем, нужно найти, есть ли во втором массиве `array2 == key` первого массива.

До меня, собственно, не доходит, как вытащить эти названия `array2` (это числа от 0), чтобы сравнить с числами key.

`$array[key][value]` - всего один, а вот `array2` много. И мне не надо ничего выводить, надо получить либо true, либо false.

Спасибо.

**Обновление**

При распечатке вот что дает. Первый массив:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 20
)
```

Второй массив:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            тут еще разные значения
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            тут еще разные значения
        )
    [14] => Array
        (
            тут еще разные значения
        )
    [20] => Array
        (
            тут еще разные значения
        )
)
```

И мне надо сравнить 20 от первого массив с 1, 3, 14, 20 от второго. Что за идиотское форматирование комментариев? Нормально не показать ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы:

```
array_key_exists( $array['id'], $_SESSION['array'])
```

Функция проверяет, есть ли в `$_SESSION['array'] значение $array['id']`.

Перелопатил кучу функций. )

Answer (score 0):

Напиши пример первого и второго массива.

**UPD:**
Решение: Грубо, но работает :)

```
$array_sec['array']['array2'] = array(array("1" = > "asdas", "id" = > "asasddas", "1423" = > "1243"));

$array['key'] = array("id" = > "123");

foreach($array['key'] as $key1 = > $value1) {
    foreach($array_sec['array']['array2'] as $key2 = > $value2) {
        foreach($value2 as $key3 = > $value3) {
            if ($key1 == $key3) {
                $temp = 'TRUE';
                break;
            } else {
                $temp = 'FALSE';
            }
        }
    }

}

echo $temp;
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Начиная c версии 5.6.0:

```
$key_needle = "key"; 
count(array_filter($array_sec["array2"], function($k) use($key_needle) {
     return $k == $key_needle;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY))) > 0;
```